# OAuth2 and OpenID Connect with angular-oauth2-oidc. Why are JWT`s saved in local storage but not (really) used?

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-oauth2-oidc

For a project I`m using this library: [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) for Support in OAuth 2 and OpenId Connect (OIDC) in Angular.

I have everything set up and all is working fine.

**MainComponent File:**

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    this.configureSSO();
  }

  configureSSO() {
    this.oAuthService.configure(authConfig);
    this.oAuthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();

    this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
      // the lib received the access_token as well as the id_token, if it was requested. 
      // If there is an id_token, the lib validated it.
      // DO STUFF WITH TOKEN HERE
    });
  }
}
```

**authConfig File:**

```
import {AuthConfig} from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

export const authConfig: AuthConfig = { /...SOME CONFIG HERE .../ }
```

**AuthGuard File:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private oAuthService: OAuthService) {
  }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if(this.oAuthService.hasValidIdToken()){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

After a successful Login on the OIDC Providers Site, I can see the access_token being saved in the Session Storage of my local Browser:

[image]

This all works perfectly, BUT, if I now proceed to **change** the token in the Session Storage, I'm still able to get into my protected routes. Although the `access_token`  was altered.
Same thing when `id_token` is changed.

--> The AuthGuard still lets me go to my protected Routes.

Can anybody enlighten me on how this would be possible?

I'm not able to find anything about how this is handled internally in the docs [Documentation angular-oauth2-oidc](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/index.html)

I'm quite sure it is NOT an Implementation Fault, but rather that the library saves the token somewhere internally, and uses the unaltered token instead, as everything else works as expected perfectly.

But WHY save the token in the Session Storage anyway if it is not (really) used?!?

> More:

If I actually **delete** the whole token from the storage, all blocked Routes are actually blocked - which is good!
Same thing happens when I alter the Expiration Time (exp) inside the JWT to something before the actual time.
So these two checks are actually working fine, but when changing `access_token` or `id_token` the AuthGuard still gets a valid Token... (maybe from inside the lib?!?)

I think there's something I don't understand about JWT in general, and why they are even saved in local/session Storage, or why the change to them does have no effect...

Any answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the basic scenario, the library will assume that every bit of JavaScript "plays nice" with session storage, effectively treating it as *private* storage for the library. If you want to clear login so that the route guards can pick it up, you should not *pry* into storage yourself, but instead call `logout` on the service. That [will effectively clear storage](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/ff82dd9b7fc81a1a001730a4013c639061fe57e9/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts#L2301-L2324).

Basically, if you delete stuff from sessionStorage (or localStorage if you'd be using that) that "belongs" to the library, you're breaking it.

Your guards are an application concern, and they should be able to trust the library (which in turn should be able to trust storage), to determine what would happen if the library considers a user "logged in".

The library itself normally does not *use* tokens at all, unless you tell it to. The most common case is to [provide a module config](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/working-with-httpinterceptors.html) to ensure the access_token is being sent along to your API. E.g.:

```
{ 
  provide: OAuthModuleConfig,
  useValue: {
    resourceServer: {
      allowedUrls: ['https://example.org/my-api'],
      sendAccessToken: true
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if you want to "protect" against other code meddling with the storage for the library, you can `provide` your own implementation of `OAuthStorage`, e.g.:

```
function storageFactory() {
  const privateStore = {};

  return {
    getItem(key) { return privateStore[key]; }
    removeItem(key) { delete privateStore[key]; }
    setItem(key, data) { privateStore[key] = data; }
  };
}
```

```
{ provide: OAuthStorage, useFactory: storageFactory }
```

I use a [similar method to provide `localStorage`](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/4f0df3f537282ba3175435949a92ed72a7a99392/src/app/core/core.module.ts#L11-L13) instead of `sessionStorage` in my sample repo.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I think I've already read alot about your comments on the github pages too I think :) I still have one thing to ask: So if the library is relying on the session/local storage, why does it still report hasValidIdToken() === true when infact the token in the storage isnt valid anymore (after altering it manually)? I think this is the only thing I dont understand...And yes I will call `logout` when really wanting to delete the token. It was more of a curiosity to just know why the lib still reports hasValidIdToken() == true even in cases where this should not be true anymore

Comment: I suggest [checking the source code](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/ff82dd9b7fc81a1a001730a4013c639061fe57e9/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts#L2255-L2270) and possibly stepping through it with the debugger for your specific scenario, to see why it would still return true in your app under specific circumstances. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, sorry to bother you. Do you think you could take a look a this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588191/angular-oauth2-oidc-what-part-of-the-configuration-retrieves-the-token-and-whe